# How to install pycaret python library in mac Mojave

Tags: python, pip, conda, pycaret

I want to install `pycaret` library in Mac Mojave 10.14.

However when I try to do `pip3 install pycaret` I get below error -

`XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?`

When I do `conda list` I get a list of libraries installed. However, I find 2 xgboost libraries there -

```
xgboost                   1.0.2            py36h0130604_1    conda-forge
xgboost                   1.1.0                     <pip>
```

I have seen some links online wherein xgboost is installed from source. However, I dont want to go through that route.

What is the best way to install `pycaret`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help (from https://pycaret.org/install/)

**For MAC OS**

MAC users will have to install LightGBM separately using Homebrew, or it can be built using CMake and Apple Clang (or gcc). See the instructions below:

Install CMake (3.16 or higher):

```
>> brew install cmake
Install OpenMP
>> brew install libomp
```

Run the following commands in terminal:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
mkdir build ; cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
```

Comment: may be a bit outdated, but will this work for an M1 chip?